# Connection timeout error when connecting Amazon RDS my SQL database from Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker

(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on <endpoint_name> (timed out)")

The database status is available
I changed the access to public (I prefer to have another option without changing to public)
The security group rules of RDS seems defaultly allowed for all traffic. So I dint change any
Nothing done to security groups of Sagemaker. Dont know where to make the changes

Comment: there's probably not enough info here to really help but it does sound like it's probably a network reachability issue so double check the security rules there and make sure you are talking to the public hostname of your RDS instance + specifying the correct port.
If you want to keep it on the private network then you will need to talk to it from within that network... either you can have something like a EC2 server which is public then you jump onto it from there or set up a AWS ClientVPN which allows access to your private subnets

Answer (score 1):

I found that the connection cannot be done with default RDS security group rules. I had to add a new inbound rule to the security group associated with the database instance created. That is add a custom TCP for port 3306 and ip Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0)

Further through RDS , we are only creating a database instance, To insert data , we need to create a database/schema which I did using MYSQL workbench.

Comment: Yes right !
Custom TCP is the best way